# Apex Trigger with custom objects

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

2 custom objects

> 1.Merchandise 
>   2.invoice

whenever a new merchandise is created an auto invoice has to be created.As am new to apex,please bear with me.Any one please correct my code.

code:

```
  trigger createinvoice on Merchandise2__c (after insert,after update) {

 list<Invoice2__c>line = new list<Invoice2__c>();

 for(Merchandise2__c mer:Trigger.new){
    Invoice2__c li = new  Invoice2__c();
    line =[select id from Invoice2__c ];
    li.name = mer.Name;
    li.Status__c='open';
    li.id = mer.id; 

    line.add(li);
 }

   insert line;
}
```

Comment: Please remember one golden rule in Apex programming.... NEVER PUT SOQL query IN A LOOP!!!..... you'll hit the governor limits easily

Comment: @BlackMamba hey thankyou for the golden rule.

Answer (score 0):

First remove the after update from your trigger unless you want a new invoice created each time someone updates the Merchandise record.

I'm not sure what you were trying to accomplish with the select line.
"line =[select id from Invoice__c];" this doesn't seem to accomplish anything.   Also you're trying to set the id field of the invoice to the id of the merchandise record.  You can't do that.  You'll need a lookup field on the Invoice record that points to merchandise.  Below I called it merchandiseKeyField.

Hope this helps.

```
trigger createinvoice on Merchandise2__c (after insert,after update) {
   //if you don't remove after Update then check which trigger
   if(Trigger.IsInsert){
        list<Invoice2__c> invoices = new list<Invoice2__c>();
         for(Merchandise__c mer: trigger.new){
             invoices.add(new Invoice2__c(li.name = mer.name,
                                          li.merchandiseKeyField = mer.id); 
         }
         insert invoices;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Psymm...hi thank you for suggesting me ....i  will make changes in the code as you mentioned and will try agian in executing the code.

Answer (score 0):

replace your loop with this:

```
for(Merchandise2__c mer:Trigger.new){
   Invoice2__c li = new  Invoice2__c();
   li.name = mer.Name;
   li.Status__c='open';
   line.add(li);
}
```

Comment: @Daniel...hey tnq for ur code i tried it but it did not worked....am just able to create merchandise record,a s merchandise and invoice dont have lookup relation ship,i need to match the merchandise id with invoice id....but am not able to do tat...

Comment: @Sravanthy sorry I'm not following... what do you mean they don't have lookup but you need to match the ids... 
if you can't save invoice, can you sent us what sort of error you get?